# How to exclude properties from bean to json at runtime

Tags: java, json-lib

I want to exclude properties from bean to json using json-lib at runtime.
How can i do it?
I have tried using propertyFilter of jsonconfig, I am not sure if its at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code-snippet based on the sample code at [Filtering Properties in JSON Advanced Features](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/advanced.html) that might be useful.

```
PropertyFilter pf = new PropertyFilter(){  
   public boolean apply( Object source, String name, Object value ) {  
      if( value != null && Number.class.isAssignableFrom( value.getClass() ) ){  
         return true;  
      }  
      return false;  
   }  
};

PrimitiveBean bean = new PrimitiveBean();  
JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();  
jsonConfig.setJsonPropertyFilter(pf); 
JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject( bean, jsonConfig );
```

You could set a different function to the JSON Config before you serialize the bean into a JSON object... in case that's what you meant by run time.